# Why using Rebass over Theme UI?

Tags: reactjs, rebass, theme-ui

I chose [Rebass](https://rebassjs.org/) as a component library for my app. Because Rebass is unopinionated about theming, it needs a theming library. Fine, I chose [Theme UI](https://theme-ui.com/) to define my theme and then I started to build my app.

I quickly noticed that all the React components (Box, Flex, Card, Link, etc.) are available in both Rebass and Theme UI. When browsing both documentations, the differences are hard to tell.

What am I missing if I remove Rebass completely? What is the purpose of this library?

Answer (score 0):

Rebass and theme-ui are different libraries but following the same styled ecosystem. Both of the library has it's own theming capability. You can use the both at the same time though it is not required.

Comment: what do you mean by "own theming capability"? both have same `sx` prop,  (almost ) the same components. Both even use 'emotion'. What one use-case over the other or how one can be used at the same time if essentially both do the same thing?

Comment: You can use rebass for creating component if it is more suited to you and use themeprovider from theme ui or react.In the production site it will not creating garbage as we have to define the package from which it will be loaded. I agreed with you about using single package for the same thing. Thank you